# How to activate Portrait Effects using depth data in iOS 12

Tags: ios, camera, photo, core-image, depth

I started with this code : [session 507 WWDC 2017](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/)

**COMPLETELY EDITED**

In iOS camera Roll I can activate "Portrait effect" during the editing of the image taken from my app.
Now I want to know how can I save directly the picture with this effect already activated?

I think my code is right because I can save the depth metadata.

I activate the bool in session configuration

`self.photoOutput.depthDataDeliveryEnabled = YES;`

and in capture output session I update the settings:

`photoSettings.depthDataDeliveryEnabled = self.photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled;`

and this is in my delegate :

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCapturePhotoOutput *)captureOutput didFinishProcessingPhoto:(AVCapturePhoto *)photo error:(nullable NSError *)error
{
    if ( error != nil ) {
        NSLog( @"Error capturing photo: %@", error );
        return;
    }

    self.photoData = [photo fileDataRepresentation];

}
```

but I do not understand why in system camera roll I don't have the " portrait badge", but It only appears during the editing :

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

This is the method I use to save the photo:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCapturePhotoOutput *)captureOutput didFinishCaptureForResolvedSettings:(AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings *)resolvedSettings error:(NSError *)error
{
    if ( error != nil ) {
        NSLog( @"Error capturing photo: %@", error );
        [self didFinish];
        return;
    }

    if ( self.photoData == nil ) {
        NSLog( @"No photo data resource" );
        [self didFinish];
        return;
    }

    [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^( PHAuthorizationStatus status ) {
        if ( status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ) {
            [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{

                PHAssetResourceCreationOptions *options = [[PHAssetResourceCreationOptions alloc] init];
                options.uniformTypeIdentifier = self.requestedPhotoSettings.processedFileType;

                PHAssetCreationRequest *creationRequest = [PHAssetCreationRequest creationRequestForAsset];
                [creationRequest addResourceWithType:PHAssetResourceTypePhoto data:self.photoData options:options];

                if ( self.livePhotoCompanionMovieURL ) {

                    PHAssetResourceCreationOptions *livePhotoCompanionMovieResourceOptions = [[PHAssetResourceCreationOptions alloc] init];
                    livePhotoCompanionMovieResourceOptions.shouldMoveFile = YES;
                    [creationRequest addResourceWithType:PHAssetResourceTypePairedVideo fileURL:self.livePhotoCompanionMovieURL options:livePhotoCompanionMovieResourceOptions];

                }

            } completionHandler:^( BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error ) {
                if ( ! success ) {
                    NSLog( @"Error occurred while saving photo to photo library: %@", error );
                }

                [self didFinish];
            }];
        }
        else {
            NSLog( @"Not authorized to save photo" );
            [self didFinish];
        }
    }];
}
```

So how can I save my photo with the portrait effect activated?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Where exactly does it return 'null' value, considering that it is a void method? In 'self.photoData'?

Comment: " self.photoData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageFromCIImage, 1.0);" . photoData in null

Comment: How exactly are you saving it to album? Could be something to do with missing https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcollectionsubtype/smartalbumdeptheffect

Comment: I add an update with the method that I use @MaximVolgin

Comment: PHAssetChangeRequest -> PHAsset -> photoDepthEffect: PHAssetMediaSubtype

Comment: @MaximVolgin PHAssetMediaSubtype is a readonly property according to this : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset/1624775-mediasubtypes?language=objc

Comment: Did you ever solve this? @BlackRock

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HEIF format, not JPEG.
Write it out with depth data in 'option' parameter.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/2902269-heifrepresentation

**UPDATE**: 
Apparently, it is also possible to provide depth data in 'option' parameter for JPEG! -
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1642214-jpegrepresentation

**UPDATE#2**: I totally misunderstood your question! Your problem can be solved by creating *CGImage* from *CIImage* first, i.e. `let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)` (in Swift) where 'context' is an instance of *CIContext*.

**UPDATE#3** (for the edited question): My guess is that is has to do with missing `photoDepthEffect: PHAssetMediaSubtype` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetmediasubtype/2765283-photodeptheffect) which you can set on `PHAsset` via `PHAssetChangeRequest`.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/2902269-heifrepresentation (add depth data in 'options' parameter)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can not make it. Every attempt returns me a null value.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the issue. See my update #2 in the answer!

Comment: Did you try 'context.createCGImage' btw?

Comment: Yes I try and solve the original problem, now I re-edit the question to be totally clear

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to add mediaSubtypes to PHAssets. I'm not entirely sure how these are calculated either though; I am saving images with custom depth maps and successfully loading them again, but cannot find any way to assign them the `photoDepthEffect` subtype. I have the feeling it ought to be handled by the system when the necessary metadata is provided, but I've not yet worked out what that metadata is.